# Azure Key Vault Quickstart fails to provide key vault client

Tags: azure-keyvault

I am learning the Azure Key Vault.  I am trying to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net.  I have created a vault in the portal, assigned an access policy for a user account.  I have seen the vault in the protal, and I have seen that the user has   I have set the environment variable value.  I use an 'az login' command at a prompt to use that account.  From the prompt I run the code in the quickstart.  It prompts for a secret.  I enter 'bob.'  It throws an exception.

"Creating a secret in [...]-key-vault called 'mySecret' with the value 'bob' ...Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details.You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS70002: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.%22)

The exception is at

```
await client.SetSecretAsync(secretName, secretValue);
```

I think the problem is coming from

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

The client is not able to send tokens that the vault accepts.  I am at a loss.  I have had a couple of people with some expertise in using the Vault review this code and they haven't been able to provide insight.  Any help?

Here is the code, from the example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace key_vault_console_app
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string secretName = "mySecret";
            var keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
            var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";

            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

            Console.Write("Input the value of your secret > ");
            var secretValue = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write($"Creating a secret in {keyVaultName} called '{secretName}' with the value '{secretValue}' ...");
            await client.SetSecretAsync(secretName, secretValue);
            Console.WriteLine(" done.");

            Console.WriteLine("Forgetting your secret.");
            secretValue = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine($"Your secret is '{secretValue}'.");

            Console.WriteLine($"Retrieving your secret from {keyVaultName}.");
            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
            Console.WriteLine($"Your secret is '{secret.Value}'.");

            Console.Write($"Deleting your secret from {keyVaultName} ...");
            DeleteSecretOperation operation = await client.StartDeleteSecretAsync(secretName);
            // You only need to wait for completion if you want to purge or recover the secret.
            await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(" done.");

            Console.Write($"Purging your secret from {keyVaultName} ...");
            await client.PurgeDeletedSecretAsync(secretName);
            Console.WriteLine(" done.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Comment: I am studying the answer.  I expect to get to know today.  Using UserNamePasswordCredential and registering an app is a new section of the platform for me; a lot to digest.

Comment: I see, please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: This worked.  I was able to write a secret to the vault using name and password credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Sure the root reason for it. But If you want to use a user account to login to Azure and access your key vault, using `UsernamePasswordCredential()` could be a workaround here.

To use `UsernamePasswordCredential()`, you should register a client application in Azure AD: Go to Azure portal =>Azure Active Directory => New registration

[image]

Note its application ID:
[image]

Go to API permissioms, and grant key vault `user_impersonation` permission so that users could access key vault via this app.
[image]
[image]
Click "Grant admin consent for.." to finish the permission grant process.

Go to the "Authentication" blade, turn on "Allow public client flows" so that Azure will consider this app as a public client:
[image]

Try the code below to create a secret:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace key_vault_console_app
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string secretName = "mySecret2";
            var keyVaultName = "<your kv name>";
            var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";

            var userCred = new UsernamePasswordCredential("<user account name>", "<user password>", "<your tenant name/id>", "<client application ID WHCIH we created above>");

            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), userCred);

            Console.Write("Input the value of your secret > ");
            var secretValue = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write($"Creating a secret in {keyVaultName} called '{secretName}' with the value '{secretValue}' ...");
            await client.SetSecretAsync(secretName, secretValue);
            Console.WriteLine(" done.");

        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This worked.  I am able to add a secret to a vault using the name and password of an account, with impersonation, and an app registration.

Comment: @SkipSaillors,glad to know it is helpful : )